# 20.04 LTS PC not starting BCS of Noatime

Tags: boot, 20.04, mount, ssd, fstab

yesterday I changed my main system from Windows 10 Ubuntu. The installation and everything went fine. I then watched an Video on what to do after the installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

One step was to change the SSD writes on Ubuntu which demanded to change /etc/fstab. I changed the file from "errors=remount-ro 0" to "noatime.errors=remount-ro 0"
Now I can't log into my Pc.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: The place for the noatime flag is in the line which specifies the UUID of the drive so it should be set like this `UUID=fa81fdeb-f197-4646-9f62-098c0dab068f /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the large community of people who have broken their install by making a mistake in `fstab`. I am a long time member.

You can fix it.

- Boot the pc to a live environment using a USB - the one you installed with is fine.
- mount the / drive with the bad `fstab` on it. (You can just find the drive in the file manager and click it.)
- edit `fstab` on that drive and fix it
- reboot

In future do a `sudo mount -a` after editing `fstab`, that will sometimes show if you made mistakes.